# Which tool usually use Ruby on Rails developers to handle administration of MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have Ruby on Rails application which is using MySQL database. For now I'm using phpmyadmin. But it requires PHP and Apache to run. Which tool usually use Rails developers to handle administration of MySQL?

Comment: The mysql command line client.

Comment: Do you mean something like phpMyAdmin? But for ruby?

Comment: yep. Something like phpmyadmin. It's not so comfortably to use command line. I could be wrong. However if use command line only for view DB data it's not bad. Migrations can avoid from make changes directly to DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a GUI try [Navicat](http://navicat.com/).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, my experience is that Rails developers tend to use the command line to create a mySQL user and ActiveRecord rake tasks for the rest: `rake db:create`, `rake db:migrate` etc.

Comment: and `rails console` for viewing data?

Comment: Yes, and you can prettify output with Hirb and AwesomePrint gems.

Comment: Have a problems using both of theese gems in `rails console`. It's works in `irb` but `require 'hirb'` (or `require 'ap'` ) raises an error (gems was installed). But that is another thread =)

Comment: I think that the command line is the way to go as it's faster (for me).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a mix of the mysql client, the rails console and Sequel Pro that is free but only running on macosx (it's a great piece of software by the way)